# Test a function by passing it as props in Router using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, use-state

I'm new to writing testcases for functioanl components in react. I have a below functional component where I need to write a test case for checkCreated() function, it calls a useState function inside it.

```
function TestComponent() {
 const [Icon, setIcon] = useState(false);
 const checkCreated = status => {
   setIcon(status);
   };

<Router>
  <Route exact path="/test" component={test} />            
  <Route exact path="/sample1" render={props => ( <Sample1 {...props} checkCreated ={ checkCreated } /> )} />
  <Route exact path="/sample2" render={props => ( <Sample2 {...props} checkCreated ={ checkCreated } /> )} />
  />
  </Router>
export default TestComponent;
```

Can someone please help me in writing testcase to cover checkCreated() using Router.

Comment: How do you use or trigger `checkCreated`?

Comment: I'm passing the checkCreated through props for components present in Router.
<Router>
            <Route exact path="/test" component={test} />            
            <Route exact path="/sample1" render={props => ( <Sample1 {...props} checkCreated ={ checkCreated } /> )} />
            <Route exact path="/sample2" render={props => ( <Sample2 {...props} checkCreated ={ checkCreated } /> )} />
            />
         </Router>
            />
         </Router>
So I need to test Sample1 and Sample2 components in the Router with that props, so I hope this is clear.

Comment: please add these information to your post, the comment is not a good place to put code.